# How to bind WinForm's listbox selecteditems

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, listbox, multi-select

I have a listbox of "all the choices" and an object that has 0 to all of those choices selected (so listbox with multivalue selectionmode). And I need to select all the object's choices selected in that listbox.

So I binded the ListBox.Datasource to the list of all available choices and tried to find a way to bind that object choices to the Listbox SelectedItems property, but I had no success on finding any information on how to do that.

### EXAMPLE

let's say we have 3 tables: Students, Courses and StudentsCourses. So in the Student's form I would need to have a listbox with all the available Courses and in that list selected all the Students courses that is in his StudentsCourses table.

**Is it possible to get this using databinding?**

### THE WAY I TRIED IT

```
//1. getting the available list
    List.DataSource = ..the list of all the courses
    List.DisplayMember = "Name";
    List.ValueMember = "Id";

//2. selecting the appropriate items in the list
    List.SelectedItems.Clear();                    
    foreach (var c in student.StudentsCourses)
    {
        //in this strange case Id is equal to the index in the list...
        List.SetSelected(c.CourseId, true);
    }

//instead of this "2." part I was hoping to use something like this:
    List.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItems", student.StudentsCourses, "CourseId");
```

but when I try to do that I get an error: **Cannot bind to property 'SelectedItems' because it is read-only**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got you right, but if I did, yes, you can do it.

**For example:**

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, Course>> coursesList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Course>>();
List<Course> cList = // Get your list of courses

foreach (Course crs in cList)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, Course> kvp = new KeyValuePair<string, Course>(crs.Name, crs);
    cList.Add(kvp);
}

// Set display member and value member for your listbox as well as your datasource
listBox1.DataSource = coursesList;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"; // First value of pair as display member
listBox1.ValueMember = "Value"; // Second value of pair as value behind the display member

var studentsList = // Get your list of students somehow

foreach (Student student in studentsList)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Course> item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        // If students course is value member in listBox, add it to selected items
        if (student.Course == item.Value)
            listBox1.SelectedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Hopefully you got the logic out of this. Since you gave zero code, I can't help you any better. Cheers!

Comment: @Prokursors You made it work right? I did it this way on my random application.

Comment: Well I did it in a similar manner you suggest, but I somehow thought maybe there is a more simple way, like using a binding to selecteditems, something like that...

Comment: @Prokurors I don't think so, but you can always hope someone will post an easy answer. Sometimes, there's just no easy way to do things =P

Comment: your right :) I am just trying to keep code smaller when possible - that's why I try to find a simpler solutions when possible, but in this case it seems there is no databinding possibility for the selecteditems i guess

Comment: My solution is somehow giving unexpected results (like selecting more items than needed), but your seems to work properly - so I am accepting your solution as an answer - thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi, Smola I am having one unexpected result using your solution, maybe You could take a look - share some ideas what could cause that behaviour?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352995/multi-value-listbox-automatically-selects-undesired-item