# Multi value ListBox automatically selects undesired item

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have an object that has some attributes from the list selected - let's say a Promotion that can have 0 to X communication channels. To display/edit this information I am using a listbox with option SelectionMode==MultiExtended.

But in some cases it is behaving strangely

1. I have Promotion with 2 communication channels selected (first and last out of three channels),
2. I click on a second channel (that previously was the only unselected channel) and know it shows, that 1st and 2nd channels are selected (I placed a check at the beginning of the listbox SelectedIndexChanged event - and it shows that SelectedItems.Count==2, although I clicked on a single item not holding Ctrl or Shift keys) **and in this case SelectedIndexChanged event is triggered twice** in all other cases it is triggered just once
3. This happens only after the first time I open this dialogform, if I manually select 1st and 3rd item of Channels, and then click on the 2nd item - then it works properly

### Screencast of a problem in action

http://screencast.com/t/lVs0e9oau

### This is how I load list of all possible channels into listbox

```
foreach (var ct in Promotion_operations.Configuration.PromoCommunicationTypes)
{
    KeyValuePair<string, PromotionCommunicationType> nct = 
        new KeyValuePair<string, PromotionCommunicationType>(ct.Name, ct);
    communications.Add(nct);
}
PromotionCommunicationList.DataSource = communications; //Promotion_operations.Configuration.PromoCommunicationTypes;
PromotionCommunicationList.DisplayMember = "Key";
PromotionCommunicationList.ValueMember = "Value";
```

### This is how I load selecteditems based on Promotion's data

```
private void LoadSelectedCommunicationsList(ListBox lstbox, List<PromotionCommunication> communications)
{
    lstbox.SelectedItems.Clear();
    foreach (var ct in communications)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lstbox.Items.Count; j++)
        {                    
            if (ct.CommunicationType.Id == ((KeyValuePair<string, PromotionCommunicationType>)lstbox.Items[j]).Value.Id)
            {
                lstbox.SelectedItems.Add(lstbox.Items[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### What could be the cause of this behaviour?

that clicking on one previously unselected list selects both - newly selected item and first item of the list?

Comment: so what you are saying is,you have for example 10 items in listbox and you select for example the third one,what else will be selected?

Comment: @terrybozzio the third and also the first would be selected, but when i repeat it second time then it works properly. Actually it is happening only in one specific scenario (the one I described - if initially there are 1st and 3rd item selected and i manually click on 2nd item - in the result i get 1st and 2nd items selected)

Comment: @terrybozzio and in that cases when that 1st item is selected automatically - then listbox's selectedindexchanged event is triggered twice, but in other cases (when selection is working properly) this event is triggered only once

Comment: have you tried listbox.clearSelected() method?

Comment: @terrybozzio I need an option to select multiple values... and I don't see at which place I could use it? In listbox Click event? But then I should somehow filter only cases when I am not trying to multi select (not using Ctrl, Shift keys)?

Comment: i really dont acurately understand the problem.You load the form and at that point no items are selected or already 1 item is selected?...also when you load the selected items is it there that it selects the first and third item and you manually click the second item and becomes first and second?

Comment: @terrybozzio Please take a look - I added a screencast of the problem I am talking about http://screencast.com/t/lVs0e9oau

Comment: I tried your code exactly as you have posted in a new project and after I set the `listbox.SelectionMode` to `MultiExtended`, it all works fine with no problem.  Items 1 and 3 are initially selected and I click on item 2 and then only item 2 becomes selected (item 1 becomes unselected).  Do you have any other events that might affect this (whats in your SelectedIndexChanged event)?

Comment: Hey Prokursors. The code you posted should work. Have you tried going through your code with debugger to see what triggers your SelectedIndexChanged event twice?

Comment: @Smola after click event SelectedIndexChanged event is fired twice and debugger does not show that there would be a line of my code between those two triggers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PromotionCommunicationList` and `HistoryCommunicationList` are sharing the same reference to your list of objects as `DataSource`. That said, they have the same `BindingContext` and share the same `CurrencyManager`. `CurrencyManager` is remembering selected items of your `ListBox` control and that's where your conflict is created because he's saving selected items of both of your `ListBoxes`. You already found the solution for your problem because new `CurrencyManager` is created when you set *"different"* list (the copy of your original one) as `DataSource`. Another possible solution would be the creation of new `BindingContext` for one of your `ListBox` controls.
You can try this out:

```
PromotionCommunicationList.DataSource = communications;
(..)
HistoryCommunicationList.BindingContext = new BindingContext(); // Add this
HistoryCommunicationList.DataSource = communications;
```

It should solve your problem. For more information about BindingContext check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.aspx) link on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem, though **I don't really understand why it caused such a behaviour** (*if someone will answer that question, I will accept it as an answer to this question*)

I had 2 listbox-es in my form and both of them where using the same collection as a Datasource, **BUT!!!** SelectedItems was selected using code (acctually it seems that in winforms it is not possible to databind listbox's selecteditems)

### INITIALLY My code was:

```
PromotionCommunicationList.DataSource = communications;
(..)
HistoryCommunicationList.DataSource = communications;
```

### Corrected version is:

```
PromotionCommunicationList.DataSource = communications.ToList();
(..)
HistoryCommunicationList.DataSource = communications.ToList();
```

I know that ToList() makes a copy, but I don't understand what's wrong with having the same collection as DataSource for list items of 2 listbox-es? Why does this have an impact on SelectedItems collection?